# Predicting new (x,y) coordinates from existing coordinates and the raw data

Tags: r, predictive-models

I have a matrix of data (325 x 9881) and a resulting table of x,y coordinates (325 x 2). The process to obtain them was as follows:

*Matrix of data* -> **[black box calculation]** -> *x,y coordinates*

Let's assume that I can't rerun the black box calculation but would like to predict the x,y coordinates for a new matrix of (*n* x 325).

I presume the best approach is to train some sort of model but most the examples I can find rely on a discrete variable rather than a matrix of data as the input and they also typically only output a single response value per input. I would really like some advice on how to best go about this problem.

I am currently working in R. Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: If you have $n=1$ input matrix and one output coordinate set, that is not enough to train anything. If there is a one-to-one relation in the sense of 325 rows of input lead to 325 coordinate pairs and I know which of the rows lead to which coordinate pair, then we come to $n=325$. Certainly much more, but very small to investigate the influence of each of $9881$ columns in the input data. You will need to find more information about the background of thes black box.

Comment: The black box is a TSNE and I need to add new data to the graph without any of the remaining points moving around which isn't really possible with TSNE. The original author of TSNE suggested training a multivariate regression to predict new points.

Comment: So - is that a yes on the 325 to 325 relation?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you were asking a question. I tried to make it clear in the post - yes, I have a matrix of 325 samples x 9881 obs and their corresponding 325 pairs of x,y coordinates

Comment: Do you have any more comments? As mentioned, I am aware it's probably not the most straightforward or conceptually correct way to do this, but it's something I need to at least try and get to work.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing much about the black box you will probably have to try a number of approaches.

My first suggestion is to define a smallish number $n$, say $n=5$ and a distance measure, say euclidean distance. Then for each new vector of 9881 input variables find the $n$ nearest neighbors within the 325 known data sets. Take their $x$ and $y$ values and compute the predicted $\hat x_i$ as the mean of the $x_{1..5}$ and the predicted $\hat y_i$ as the mean of the $y_{1..5}$. Alternatively you can compute a weighed mean of the $x$ and $y$ values with the weights determind by the distances in a way, that a point further away from the input has less influence on the result.

My second suggestion is to use two random forests: One to predict the $\hat x$-values from the 9881 input values and one to predict the $\hat y$ values. The influence of each of the 9881 input values cannot be specified from 325 inputs but each tree within the forest will only use part of the values. Random forest with only one output, either x or y, are implemented in many software solutions and easier to find than those with value pairs as outcomes.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give both approaches a go and let you know how I get on.